# How to format date and time values when using itextpdf forms

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrobat

We're using iTextPDF to create a PDF report. It starts with a PDF form as a template. We populate it with JSON data. I have a date fields and time fields in the form, multiple date and time fields.  In JSON the date is formatted as yyyy-MM-dd and the time as 24 hour, HH:MM.  I want to display the date in the PDF as MM/dd/yyyy and the time as 12 hour format.

How can I perform a calculation or some such on the values when passed to the form? My JSON looks like this:

```
        "F_Backing1_Week": "1",
        "F_Backing1_Date": "2021-11-09",
        "F_Backing1_Time": "02:00",
        "F_Backing2_Week": "1",
        "F_Backing2_Date": "2021-11-09",
        "F_Backing2_Time": "04:30",
```

My Acrobat form is setup like:

[image]

My Java code that makes the PDF:

```
public PdfObject makePDFFromJson(String templatePath, String pdfName, String json) throws IOException {

    PdfObject pdfObject = new PdfObject();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templatePath);
    
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
    writer.setCompressionLevel(9);
    
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stream), writer);
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
    Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
    
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map<String, String> jsonMap = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()){           
        if(fields.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            logger.debug(entry.getValue());
            if(entry.getValue().contains("data:image/png;base64")) {
                logger.debug("found an image!");
                fields.get(entry.getKey()).setValue(entry.getValue().split(",")[1]);
            } else {
                fields.get(entry.getKey()).setValue(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    
    form.flattenFields();
    pdf.close();

    pdfObject.setPdfBytes(out.toByteArray());
    out.close();
    pdfObject.setPdfName(pdfName);
    return pdfObject;
}
```

How can I format these values?

Comment: For iText those fields essentially are plain text fields. If you want to display the content in a special format, you have to format a string accordingly and set that formatted string as value of the field.

Comment: Is there any way to format from within Acrobat? or will it just take whatever string I throw at it?

Comment: It actually depends. Usually you can throw anything at it using itext. But there may be some Javascript running after opening the form that reformats all fields values.